# How to define default values for variables defined in ftplugin?

Tags: vimscript, variables

Say that I have defined two files

**python.vim**

```
let b:foo="py"
let b:bar="thon"
```

**cobol.vim**

```
let b:foo="co"
let b:bar="bol"
```

and that I placed both of them in *~/.vim/ftplugin* folder.

Now assume that in my *.vimrc* I have the following

```
func! Myfun(foo,bar)
     " do something
endfunc

command MyCommand :call MyFun(b:foo, b:bar)
```

When I open a Python or Cobol file everything works fine, but when I open any other file with different filetype and try to run `:MyCommand`, then I get the **E121: Undefined variable: b:foo** for very good reasons.

A trivial solution would be to copy `command MyCommand :call MyFun(b:foo, b:bar)` in both *python.vim* and *cobol.vim* and remove it from *.vimrc* but to be honest I really don't like that solution.

I am wondering if there a way to define some default values and if so how to deal with that, or, if you have any other more elegant solution, feel free to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get()` to fill in default values:

```
command MyCommand :call MyFun(get(b:, 'foo', 'def'), get(b:, 'bar', 'ault'))
```

In this way `b:` is acting as a sort of "pseudo-dict" which has keys foo and bar.  If these variables are not defined, the defaults are substituted according to the normal `get()` behavior.

Comment: ‘Gr’ . ‘eat! ‘ . ‘Thanks!’